# Is it possible to use SSMS to access Azure SQL DB via user managed identity?

Tags: azure, ssms, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL Database via a UMI.  I can connect via local SQL creds as well as AAD creds, but not when specifying AAD - Managed Identity:

[image: SSMS Connect]

I get the following error:
[image]

I've created a SQL User associated via `CREATE USER MyUserManagedId FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` and added the role of db_owner to no avail.

All the docs and demos I've seen/read up to the point either show a System Managed ID and/or connecting via a VM and/or code, which makes me wonder if I am trying to do something that's unsupported.

Is there something magical that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, please post the error text. Can you explain why you want to do this? Managed Identities are not designed for interactive / user logins.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check, @Nick.McDermaid.  I had connection strings and client secrets in code and went down a rathole on Azure key vault & managed identities. I thought I'd first try connecting to the db using managed identities via SSMS.  I now realize it doesn't make sense given its purpose is to request a bearer token from Azure AD, which it can then present to the requested service.  SSMS is not an Azure service authorized by AAD so the identity is not known.  Unless, SSMS was running in an Azure VM, whereby I'm thinking you could use SSMS Managed Identity to sign-on. Thanks.

Comment: There's no way I'm aware of to log into Azure SQL via SSMS using a managed identity. Even from a VM with an underlying managed identity. You shouldn't need to use keyvault _at all_ with managed identities, that's one of the reasons to use them. Which service is the managed identity for?

Comment: For example if you are using Azure Data Factory, you just grant the Azure Data Factory managed identity required access with `CREATE USER` as you have done, then in your connection inside ADF, you specify managed identity. No secrets or keyvault required. It's possible to not use KeyVault at all (and personally I take great steps to avoid it). Are you trying to remove secrets from a process? What are you connecting from?

Comment: Could you please provide information about managed identity which you are using?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - if there's no way to login to Azure SQL via SSMS using a managed identity, then why is "Azure Active Directory - Managed Identity" as an option on the SSMS login screen?  See OP.
I'm on day 3 of learning keyvault & MI - it's been confusing with so much outdated/incorrect/overly complex info.  The secrets are for my asp.net core app and associated api's (client secrets when calling protected api's as well as SQL connection strings). Thx 4 the help/guidance/feedback.  Much to learn, I still have.

Comment: @Bhavani - the managed identity is an Azure SQL server/db as well as asp.net core web apps (client + api's).

Comment: Interesting: managed identity and service principal appear to be new options in the latest version of SSMS. What are you trying to do? Managed Identities and Service Principals are only intended to be used when you have some kind of middleware service that needs to authenticate. If you are trying to log in as a "human", you do not use these methods.

Comment: _The secrets are for my....  SQL connection strings_ What are you connecting from?? an asp.net app? The Azure App Service that your application is running in has a managed identity associated with it. You need to grant that access to your SQL DB, then in your SQL connection strings you just use managed identity authentication. Then there are no secrets in your connection string and in my opinion, therefore, these connection strings are configuration and _do not_ belong in keyvault.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, asp.net app. Got it, thanks. FYI: SSMS added MI as auth in 19.0 but the docs are sparse: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#190. Moving on...